# Jquery load - using variable in selector

Tags: jquery

I can't get the **rand** variable to work in this code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);      
   $('.related1').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq(1)');
   $('.related2').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq(2)');
   $('.related3').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq(rand)');
});
```

The first 2 load fine, but the one using the random number does not.

I also saw a suggestion and tried:

```
   $('.related3').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq("+rand+")');
```

But that didn't work either.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You just have a mismatch with your quotes.  Do something like this:

```
$('.related3').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq('+rand+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 $('.related3').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq('+rand+')');
```

You started the argument inside load with `'`, so you need to terminate it with another `'` and append `rand` to that string, and append this string `')'` back.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$('.related3').load('inc/related.asp .list:eq("'+rand+'")');
```

Comment: Be careful with having both single and double quotes here, as that will turn  the value of _rand_ into a string (which will break this)

Comment: @MFazio23 There'll be no problem as rand will output integer and eq will accept string...